# Can Trello card description edits be logged in activity/history?

Tags: trello

It doesn't look like adding/editing the description of a card causes any log to the activity history of a board. Is there a way to turn this on or to cause the logging to happen?

Comment: Nop it's not possible right now. Emailing `feature-ideas@trello.com` to propose such a feature looks like a good idea !

Comment: For the same question but with card titles, see http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/103491/24544

Answer (score 19):

They are logged in the JSON export of the card.

[image: Export JSON]

The current description under the `desc` key, and the previous revisions of the card are under the `actions` key, look for `old` -> `desc`.

Answer (score 6):

Trello's (non-technical) instructions for recovering the description of a card that has been changed: http://help.trello.com/article/783-recovering-the-description-of-a-card-that-has-been-changed

Which, at the end-2019, basically says that there is currently no way to do this via web interface (apart from [the already mentioned card export](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/82364/197348)), but that it is possible via API:

1. Get the card ID for the card. This is included in the URL of the card, after the /c/ - e.g. `hpAcP7IS` is the card ID for https://trello.com/c/hpAcP7IS/814-multiple-log-in-credentials
2. Go to https://trello.com/1/cards/CARD_ID/actions?filter=updateCard:desc, replacing `CARD_ID` with the card ID you noted above
3. Look for `data.old.desc` for the old descriptions

Note, one needs to have access to the card to get the change history.

Comment: Can you give a summary of what's at the link in case it goes dead sometime in the future, please?

Answer (score 3):

Editing the description of a card is not logged as a change in your activity/history, but editing the description of a board is.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Extension https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/trello-description-change/ with all Chrome-like Browsers. It lists all changes for every card an can also highlight the diffs.

I have unfortunately not found anything comparable for Firefox.