# Can I retrieve the old names for Trello cards?

Tags: trello

When you edit a card title in Trello, it doesn't add an entry to the visible history of the card. Is there a way to retrieve past titles of cards?

Comment: For the same question but with card descriptions, see http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/29050/24544

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The history of the card is logged by Trello, and there are ways to retrieve it using their API. You can also use the "Export JSON" functionality:

[image: Screenshot of "Export JSON" button]

The current title of the card is under the key `name`. The history of the card is under the key `actions`, from which you can find past names under `data` -> `old` -> `name`.